# "'what' must be a function or character string" Error during loading data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am trying to load in some data - a list of CSV files. The code below has worked for other data sets of mine, but not for this one.

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/prime/word/data")
file.age <- setwd("~/Dropbox/prime/word/data")
age_names <- dir(file.age)
one <- do.call(bind_rows,lapply(age_names,read.csv))
```

I get the following:

Error:
! Can't combine `..1$Reaction.Time`  and `..2$Reaction.Time` .
Backtrace:

1. base::do.call(bind_rows, lapply(age_names, read.csv))
2. dplyr (local) `<fn>`(...)
3. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)

Having a look through some of the data... in the "reaction time" column there is sometimes a "LOADING DELAY" value rather than a numerical value... might this be the issue?

If it is, is there a way to filter that out on the way in? I've tried appending
"%>% filter(reaction_time != "LOADING DELAY")" to the code, but I get the same issue.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It could be an issue of difference in column types.  You may try to convert all the columns to character and thenn use bind_rows i.e. `map_dfr(age_names, ~ read.csv(.x) %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` and later reconvert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could specify the column type of the specific column as `character` while reading and then it should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(age_names, ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(Reaction.Time = "c")))
```

Comment: Brilliant... that worked. Thanks a lot!

one <-  map_dfr(age_names, ~ read.csv(.x) %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)